# Are we tied to MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

It looks like there is a much faster competitor to MathJax, called [KaTeX](http://khan.github.io/KaTeX/) that was recently released. I know that for some of my longer answers ([here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10637/applying-expectation-maximization-to-coin-toss-examples/10657#10657) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23673/em-algorithm-for-two-gaussian-models/23681#23681)), edits require a refresh to properly display. Additionally, it can take some time to actually compile/display.

> Is cs.stackexchange tied to MathJax or is it possible to switch?

Not that we *must* switch. I'll admit that this isn't necessarily a massive issue, but it is nice knowing there are options.

Comment: Looks interesting! 1) SE will probably wait for stability and "here to stay"-ness before even considering a switch. 2) Since everything happens in JS, it might be possible to make the switch locally by user script.

Comment: [Related question on math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16809/3330) -- apparently KaTeX does not support many features as of now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this is worth looking at. Since this concernes more than one site, [I pushed the matter upstream](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239433/a-contender-for-mathjax).